# Sublime 3 - Modify Matching Tags

Tags: html, tags, sublimetext3, matching

What changes are needed to modify tag matching in Sublime 3, Build 3143, from an underline to background color.  Much of the documentation I have been able to find online seems either out of date or incomplete.  Below is an example of the desired effect.

[image: matching html tags]

Comment: Can't you just hold CTRL as you click on the desired elements? What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: Two things.  Sublime highlights matching tags with an underscore when the cursor is within one of the tags but does not include the opening and closing <>.  Would like to also highlight the <> characters and change the background color.  The example is from Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Core Sublime only matches brackets and tags with a dotted underline, and as far as I'm aware it's not possible to visually modify the style in the general case.

To get around that, you can use the [BracketHighlighter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter) package to do what you want. Once you've installed it, you will need to configure it to your liking, for which you should check out the documentation.

Briefly, in order to get it to do something like what you've outlined above, you want to select `Preferences > Package Settings > BracketHighlighter > Bracket Settings` from the menu (`Preferences` is under `Sublime Text` if you're on MacOS) and then add the following to the default settings:

```json
"user_bracket_styles": {
    "tag": {
        "icon": "tag",
        "color": "region.purplish",
        "style": "solid"
    },
}
```

Note that `region.purplish` as a potential scope name was added in Sublime build 3148, so for build 3143 you will need to select a scope name that is colored the way that you want in whatever color scheme you're using. For example, if you're using the `Monokai` color scheme, the scope `constant.language` looks purple.

Comment: Seems strange that this modification is not possible when the syntax and color files are accessible.  Some of the tag matching options can already be customized such as underline style and foreground color of the tag text by changing tagsOptions and tagsForeground in the theme file.